# Localhost styles and scripts not displayed in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, .htaccess, firefox

I'm developing a website locally and pages are properly displayed in Chrome and Safari. Unfortunately, in Firefox, the HTML is rendered but without the styles and scripts mentioned between the head tags.

Several elements to know:

- I use a Mac with El Capitan system.
- I use MAMP as a local server with the ports 80 and 3306.
- I have defined symbol links in a .htaccess file to have clean URLs.

Once again, everything is working well in Chrome and Safari (no console error). I have this issue on Firefox only.

Does someone have already encountered this issue and know how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: In your Network Tab, can you see what's the MIME Type and HTTP Status code please?

Comment: Yes. there is a 200 status for all the files and the MIME types are correct (html, css, js). Is it what you meant?

Comment: Yes. Can you post the response of the HTML in the browser?